# How to repeat textboxes and check box dynamically using repeaters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have requirement in my application where I am struck . These is my scenario:

Initially I need to show up two text boxes with a check box and a button. upon clicking the button we need to generate one more row. Like wise we need to create multiple rows dynamically.

Initially I tried with Table Control but after struggling a lot, I came to know that we can create only one row dynamically  using Table Control. So now I am planning to do in repeater control.

Comment: You should accept answers to some of your old questions, otherwise people wont be very attracted to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of scenario, it would be better to use the `GridView` Control Instead, take a look here some working examples:

http://www.revenmerchantservices.com/page/gridview-add-new-row.aspx

http://amitpatriwala.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/inserting-new-row-in-gridview-in-aspnet-20/